# Merge 2 json array objects based on a common property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I got 2 Json arrays with some common field. But they are not sorted in any specific order. I want to be able to merge them based on a property.

```
var merge = require('deepmerge');
var one = [{
  id:1
},
{
  id:2
}];
var two = [{
  id:2,
  name:"test1"
},
{
  id:1,
  name:"test2"
}];

console.log(merge(one,two));
```

deepmerge results in blind merge, first element with first element from the other array.

`[ { id: 2, name: 'test1' }, { id: 1, name: 'test2' } ]`

I know its possible to manually iterate thru one array, find the matching node from the other array and merge them...wondering if there is any library to do this. Thoughts?

Comment: yes, all is possible, but what do you want exactly?

Comment: @nina I got 2 unsorted arrays but with atleast one common property like I mentioned above and want to merge them. Does that help?

Comment: not really, please add some more example. and the wanted result of merging.

Comment: want one merged array as a result, like

[ { id: 1, name: 'test2' },
  { id: 2, name: 'test1' },
  { id: 3, name: 'test3' } ]

Comment: i see nothing to merge, just take two as result.

Comment: what if below represents my 2 arrays

`var one = [{
  id:1,
  score:100
},
{
  id:2,
  score:200
},
{
    id:4,
    score:400
}];
var two = [{
  id:2,
  name:"test1"
},
{
  id:1,
  name:"test2"
},
{
    id:3,
    name:"test3"
}];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115722/discussion-between-sahas-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a function and define the common key, on which the merging should group. It works with unsorted data.

```js
function merge(arrays, key) {
    var r = [],
        hash = Object.create(null);

    arrays.forEach(function (a) {
        a.forEach(function (o) {
            if (!hash[o[key]]) {
                hash[o[key]] = {};
                r.push(hash[o[key]]);
            }
            Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
                hash[o[key]][k] = o[k];
            });
        });
    });
    return r;
}

var one = [{ id: 1, score: 100 }, { id: 2, score: 200 }, { id: 4, score: 400 }],
    two = [{ id: 2, name: "test1" }, { id: 1, name: "test2" }, { id: 3, name: "test3" }],
    merged = merge([one, two], 'id');

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort both arrays before hand?

```
one.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
two.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
```

Now that the arrays are sorted you should be able to merge them properly:

```
console.log(merge(one, two));
```

Comment: thanks.. I did try this.. it didn't work when I've an array element in 1st array that doesn't have any matching in 2nd. Below is an example 
Sorted array - one
 [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 4 } ]
sorted array - two
 [ { id: 1, name: 'test2' },
  { id: 2, name: 'test1' },
  { id: 3, name: 'test3' } ]
merges array

[ { id: 1, name: 'test2' },
  { id: 2, name: 'test1' },
  { id: 3, name: 'test3' } ]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [merge](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) in lodash. Subsequent sources overwrite property assignments of previous sources. So this will overwrite the subsequent id's

```
var users = {
  'data': [{ 'user': 'barney' }, { 'user': 'fred' }]
};

var ages = {
  'data': [{ 'age': 36 }, { 'age': 40 }]
};

_.merge(users, ages);
// → { 'data': [{ 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 }, { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 40 }] }
```