# Join Two Arrays on a Matching Object Property

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two arrays that I would like to join

```
const users = [{ user_id: 100, name: 'Bob' }, { user_id: 101, name: 'Joe' }]

const departments [{ id: 900, manager: 100 }, { id: 901, manager: 101 }]
```

I want to create a new `departments` array that contains the user's `name` by matching the `user_id` property to the department's `manager` property.

Is there a simple way to achieve this in `lodash` (or plain Javascript) ?

The new array would look like this

```
[{ id: 900, manager: 100, name: 'Bob' }, { id: 900, manager: 101, name: 'Joe' }];
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @connexo I attempted this several times but came up with the same sub-par solutions, which is why I'm posting to SO. I'm not lazy

Comment: Take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053193/merge-2-json-array-objects-based-on-a-common-property) as inspiration and let us know what did you come with

Comment: You still haven't attempted at using e.g. `_.map` from lodash or `Array.prototype.map` yourself.

Comment: @connexo I did arrive at the `_.map` function today and was trying it out, lodash is fairly new to me. But by all means downvote my posts and assume I'm doing nothing, super helpful. 

Comment: `"I'll spare the code for brevity"` -- not good. Please show for *clarity*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a Map for faster lookup, and then make the mapping:

```js
const users = [{ user_id: 100, name: 'Bob' }, { user_id: 101, name: 'Joe' }],
    departments = [{ id: 900, manager: 100 }, { id: 901, manager: 101 }];

const names = new Map(users.map( user => [user.user_id, user.name] )),
    res = departments.map( dep => Object.assign({ name: names.get(dep.manager) }, dep) );

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Note that the extra step of creating a Map will lead to *O(n)* time efficiency as opposed to *O(n²)* when using an array searching method in each iteration. This is not relevant for small user arrays, but will be when working with larger array sizes.

Comment: Even though this is not as concise as the other answer, this should imo be the chosen answer as it rightfully points out that in the given circumstances using `Array.find` on every iteration of `Array.map` can cause performance issues.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do it with just JavaScript using `map` and `find`:

```js
const users = [{ user_id: 100, name: 'Bob' }, { user_id: 101, name: 'Joe' }]
const departments = [{ id: 900, manager: 100 }, { id: 901, manager: 101 }]

const result = departments
  .map(d => ({
    ...d,
    name: users.find(u =>
      u.user_id === d.manager).name
  }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This will probably make OP think you're using a different language. :)

Comment: @connexo I come to this community for help when I need it. Why are you putting down others who might not know as much as you do?

Comment: That is your perception. It actually contained critique of mdatsev's answer: Obviously OP is not too familiar with modern JS. Giving a full blown ES6 solution will probably rather confuse than help OP (even if it is a beautiful solution by itself). You might want to explain the new syntactic sugar you've used here.

Comment: @connexo I'm familiar with arrow functions and spread syntax, and even if I wasn't, why would that be an issue? This is literally a place or sharing knowledge and insight to those who need help, not being a troll.

Comment: You're fighting a pseudo enemy. The real enemy is unwillingness to read documentation and try out by yourself.

Comment: Could've sworn I said I made multiple attempts and was looking for a better solution. Clearly your enemy is reading & comprehension lol

Comment: `My attempt at this involved 3 nested forEach loops` = single attempt, not tried Array.map or _.map.

Comment: Thank you @mdatsev for your helpful answer